Trouble with Google OAuth in iOS WebView Wrapped Application
I'm new to emulating and authentication etc, using WKWebView to load my web application and wrap my webview into my si/emulator. However when trying to login with the google auth redirect I get 403 disallowed_useragent. Any tips for an easy solution?
Tried to use a WKWebView to load your web application running at localhost:3000 and handle Google OAuth 2.0 authentication.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use
webView.customUserAgent = "Your custom user agent"

to change the WKWebView user agent to anything you want eg. MyApp/1.0
this will prevent the google login page to throw 403 disallowed_useragent
